# Programmatically add stamp layer to PDF document

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I'm looking for a way to add an extra layer to a PDF document. The layer should be on top of existing layers and should display a text I want to put on there, kind of like a watermark. At the moment we have a way of doing this, but this just adds the text onto the picture embedded in the PDF, that's not what I want. Anyone has any ideas if there are libraries (free ones would be great) which do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Image watermark to Pdf while Creating it using iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041718/adding-image-watermark-to-pdf-while-creating-it-using-itextsharp)

Comment: [Creating watermarks in PdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Watermark-sample.ashx).

Comment: Will try, I need to check that the text on the PDF remains text and doesn't get converted to an image. That seemed to happen on other examples I tried. But thanks! I'll let you know.

Comment: Highly recommend iTextSharp as well. I use it almost every day and it does exactly what you are asking for and doesn't rasterize anything. In fact, it actually doesn't have the capability to rasterize anything.

Answer (score 4):

We user MigraDoc,

http://www.pdfsharp.net/MigraDocOverview.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

More specifically the PdfSharp library in PdfSharp.dll,

```
PdfDocument doc = PdfReader.Open(pdf1Point4FileDataStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify)

foreach (PdfPage page in doc.Pages)
{
    page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Portrait;
    var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append, XPageDirection.Downwards);

    gfx.DrawString(approvalWatermark, approvalFont, watermarkBrush, new XPoint((page.Width - maxWidth + approvalDiff) / 2 - space - moveLeft, page.Height / 2 - height1 - space), format);
}
```

Just a bit of code taken from our project, so it is a bit incomplete. Take a look at the library and classes, there will be some documentation around.